# Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser' builder's node package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku. Heroku local web works completely fine. I've tried adding npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular but it doesn't help and I also couldn't find anything similar on the internet. Deploying to Heroku works fine until it gets to ng build --prod command which can be found in "postinstall" inside angular package.json.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && cd public && npm install @angular/cli -g && npm install",
    "heroku-cleanup": "cd ./public && patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^19.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "pg": "^8.7.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.10",
    "npm": "7.24.0"
  }
}
```

angular package.json

```
{
  "name": "public",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/patch-package && ng build --prod --aot",
    "heroku-cleanup": "./node_modules/.bin/patch-package"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.12",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^19.2.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to re-install the package:

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

If that does not work, you can try:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

Comment: If that was the problem it wouldn't work even locally i would say. But i did try ng update and installing it again though with no success.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder, and then running an npm install? Just trying to think of things that may help. :-)

Comment: Also shouldn't be a problem, since i run npm install in heroku post-build. I'm all out of ideas what to even try anymore

Comment: I use Azure, and it allows me to use different build machines (i.e. Windows build, Ubuntu, etc.). Somehow when I hit these types of issues, selecting a different build environment works, for no apparent reason. I'm not sure if you have such options but if so it may help. These types of issue are always frustrating and you lose tons of time on it.